# How to separate string output?

Tags: sql

I have a query which output a a column name `member_name`

```
select 
LEFT(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) - 1) + ' ' 
+ SUBSTRING(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, 1) as member_name

from member
```

It output the string with the last name and first letter of first name.

How can I output in the table with the first letter and last name in different columns?

For example to have it output something like this:

```
first | last name 
-----------------
J     | DOE

B     | DOE-DOE

Z     | SMITH
```

I made a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7a74/7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
   substring(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, 1) as first_initial,
   left(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) - 1) as last_name
from
   member
```

Comment: why didnt i think about doing it on the query ... well im curious if it can be done in coldfusion output , didnt find anything online

Comment: "im curious if it can be done in coldfusion output , didnt find anything online"..? You didn't find *the documentation* online? Which details any number of ways one can split a string, dependent on the specific requirement?

Comment: @user3591637 did you see my other answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to reply to comments just yet, but as you asked in a comment in the answer, It **can be** done in cold fusion, but I'd think SQL is your better choice.

```
<cfoutput query="get_names">
  <cfset l_name = listfirst(member_name,"/")>
  <cfset f_initial = left(listlast(member_name,"/"),1)>
  <!--- if you want f_initial capitalized, use the below cfset rather than the above --->
  <cfset f_initial = ucase(left(listlast(member_name,"/"),1))>

  First initial: #f_initial#, Last name: #l_name#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

That would output, based on your fiddle:

```
First initial: J, Last Name: suarez
First initial: J, Last Name: suarez
First initial: S, Last Name: mejia
First initial: D, Last Name: orozco
```

It's a good exercise to help understand how cf works, and more importantly that there is an overlap between what your queries can do for you and what your code can but **once again** I recommend the sql solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe the best way to handle this situation is the SQL modification in my other answer, here's a way to do it in CF only, based on your fiddle's data layout.

```
<cfquery name="getMembers">
   select member_name from member
</cfquery>

<table>
   <tr><td>First</td><td>Last Name</td></tr>
   <cfoutput>
      <cfloop query="getMembers">
         <cfset aMember = ListToArray(member_name, "/")>
         <tr><td>#left(aMember[2],1)#</td><td>#aMember[1]#</td></tr>
      </cfloop>
   </cfoutput>
</table>
```